# Cause of batch requests being sent from ReportServer Database of SSRS to database engine every 5 second

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-profiler, sqlreportingservice

I've just monitored my SQL Server database requests using SQL Server Profiler. I figured that the `ReportServer` database sends 2 batch requests every 5 seconds - see image below.

I also tried it on my local database engine to make sure that no report is being called from the users but again the requests are being sent every 5 seconds same as server

[image]

I read the content of two requests which is the same for all of the requests
one of them updates `event` table of `ReportServer` database and then select top 8 from `event` table

Another one update  `notification` table and then select top 8 from `notification` table joined with three other tables

Here is the code (batch queries) inside textData column of Profiler

Request 1:

```
declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier
set @BatchID = NEWID()

UPDATE [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX)
SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
    [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
    [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 8 [EventID] 
     FROM [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX) 
     WHERE [ProcessStart] IS NULL 
     ORDER BY [TimeEntered]) AS t1
WHERE 
    [Event].[EventID] = t1.[EventID]

SELECT TOP 8
    E.[EventID], E.[EventType], E.[EventData]
FROM
    [Event] E WITH (TABLOCKX)
WHERE
    [BatchID] = @BatchID
ORDER BY 
    [TimeEntered]
```

Request 2:

```
declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier
set @BatchID = newid()

UPDATE [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX)
SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
    [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
    [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 8 [NotificationID] 
     FROM [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX) 
     WHERE ProcessStart IS NULL 
       AND (ProcessAfter IS NULL OR ProcessAfter < GETUTCDATE()) 
     ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]) AS t1
WHERE 
    [Notifications].[NotificationID] = t1.[NotificationID]

SELECT TOP 8
    -- Notification data
    N.[NotificationID], N.[SubscriptionID], N.[ActivationID],
    N.[ReportID], N.[SnapShotDate], N.[DeliveryExtension],
    N.[ExtensionSettings], N.[Locale], N.[Parameters],
    N.[SubscriptionLastRunTime], N.[ProcessStart],
    N.[NotificationEntered], N.[Attempt], N.[IsDataDriven],
    SUSER_SNAME(Owner.[Sid]),
    Owner.[UserName],
    -- Report Data
    O.[Path], N.[ReportZone], O.[Type], SD.NtSecDescPrimary,
    N.[Version], Owner.[AuthType], SR.[SubscriptionResult]
FROM
    [Notifications] N WITH (TABLOCKX) 
INNER JOIN
    [Catalog] O ON O.[ItemID] = N.[ReportID]
INNER JOIN
    [Users] Owner ON N.SubscriptionOwnerID = Owner.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SecData] SD ON O.[PolicyID] = SD.[PolicyID] AND SD.AuthType = Owner.AuthType
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   [SubscriptionResults] SR ON N.[SubscriptionID] = SR.[SubscriptionID] 
                            AND CHECKSUM(convert(nvarchar(max), N.[ExtensionSettings])) = SR.[ExtensionSettingsHash]
WHERE
    N.[BatchID] = @BatchID
ORDER BY 
    [NotificationEntered]
```

**First** I'd like to know what's the cause of these annoying requests being sent every 5 seconds, even though the result of both selects in all the requests is empty and there is no actual request to reporting service (it seems that they don't do any thing special since both the event and notification tables are empty)

And **second**, how can I stop this procedure of sending useless requests** every 5 second from the `ReportServer` database?

Do notice that I want to keep my reporting service up and running so I can't stop it's service I just want to stop the sending of useless requests.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want SSRS to continue to work as designed, I suggest you quit trying to troubleshoot this non-issue. Just let the service do its thing. Walk away, and work on something you can do something about. :)

Comment: @R. Richards thanks for answer, so-called non-issue could be an issue on a busy database server which supposed to serve about two hundred thousand request per day. I know it would have made more sense if we had separate server for report but lack of facilities, however performance (especially database server) still is very critical factor for our app

Comment: @R. Richards do you know why ReportServer send those nonsense requests???

Comment: If your application is having performance issues, the queries SSRS is running as a part of what it does are not the issue. This sounds like poor planning from an infrastructure perspective; focus on that. The only way to stop these notification queries from happening is to turn SSRS off, but I doubt that is an option.